# Why am I getting "error : expected ;" while accessing a string?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am accessing the JSP Variable in Javascript and printing it(this is exact context in my code). However, it is showing "Excepted ;" at line 9(line 9 code is document.write(na);)..

Is there any way to access the below format JSP string in javascript?

```
<%
String name = "Java Beans  \"is\" a reusable component";
%>

<html>
<head>
<script>
var na = "<%=name%>";

document.write(na);
</script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: may be try single quotes '<%= name %>'

Comment: Show us the output of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to wrap your variable - the value *contains* double-quotes which will break the output, as JavaScript will see:

```
var na = "Java Beans "is" a reusable component";
                    ^^^^^^
```

Instead do this:

```
document.write('<%=name%>');
```

...note the single quotes.

Cheers